# Newby Trouble With Remote PowerShell scripts

Tags: powershell

I do know about the double hop issue. My scenario is: I have a script I want to run  remotely that calls another script located on a network share that calls a third script located on a second network share in a different domain.

Currently what I am doing is using Credssp (I've read there can be security issues but this environment is not public facing) to pass credentials for the 1st network share that has script2. I do not have access to the computer with the second domain so I cannot setup credssp on it. In order to work around that, inside of the script2 I am using "net use" command on the third script in order for the script to be able to find the path. I am then using "Copy-Item" to copy the third script on to the machine running script2 (the remote machine).

Up to this step, everything is working when I run script1. I can see script3 is copied over onto the remote machine. When script3 is called, it should make a web request that sends text to stdout (which I pipe to Out-File in script2). However, whenever I try to run the copy of script3 (located on the remote machine) from script2 (running on the remote machine) it does not seem to do anything. If I run script2 locally on the remote machine then it works fine (file is generated from script3's output).

Any idea's on why this won't work? I've tried running script 3 using several variations of invoke-expression, invoke-command, start-process, and even trying to run with cmd. I'm also having trouble getting output on what exactly is causing the issue (stdout and stderr are many times empty when using the different commands). Am I missing some command or tool that may make this easier to troubleshoot? It almost seems like script3 is still running into a double hop issue despite it only making a web request? And if it was running into that, I thought it would have had an error returned.

There my be a better design for doing what I'm trying to do. I'm fairly new to PowerShell and may be over complicating this.

Edit: Rewrote my scripts in python and got it working.

Comment: Why are you involving four computers instead of just two?

Comment: There are only 3 computers. Script1 runs from computer1 to run script2 remotely on computer2 but is on a computer1 share. I was hoping the additional info would clarify the situation but it seems to be making it more convoluted.
The issue I'm running into is script3 being copied over and not running correctly.